# Python thread won't start using socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

i have a problem with my progam using socket and thread.

I have made a socket server who add client in a thread, but the client thread never start...

here is my code:

socket server

```
import socket, threading, logging, sys
from client_thread import ClientThread

class SocketServer:
    CLIENTS = list()

    def __init__(self, server_ip, server_port, max_connections):
        try:
            self.tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.tcpsock.bind((server_ip, server_port))
            self.tcpsock.listen(10)

            logging.info('Socket server successfully started !')
    except Exception as e:
            logging.error(format(e))

    def start(self):
        from src.realmserver.core.hetwan import EmulatorState, Core

        while (Core.STATE == EmulatorState.IN_RUNNING):
            try:
                (clientsock, (ip, port)) = self.tcpsock.accept()
                new_client = threading.Thread(target=ClientThread, args=[len(self.CLIENTS), ip, port, clientsock])
                self.CLIENTS.append(new_client)
                new_client.start()
            except Exception as e:
                print format(e)

        for client in self.CLIENTS:
            client.join()
```

and client thread

```
import logging, string, random

class ClientThread:
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_ip, client_port, socket):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_ip = client_ip
        self.client_port = client_port
        self.socket = socket
        logging.debug('(%d) Client join us !', client_id)

    def run(self):
        key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(32))

        print self.send('HC%s' % key)

        while True:
            entry = self.socket.recv(4096)
            entry.replace("\n", "")

            if not entry:
                break
            else:
                logging.debug('(%d) Packet received : %s', self.client_id, str(entry))

        self.kill()

    def send(self, packet):
        return self.socket.send("%s\x00" % packet)

    def kill(self):
        self.socket.close()
        logging.debug('(%d) Client is gone...', self.client_id)
```

sorry for bad indentation, it's the form, not my file.

Please help me :(

Thank you in advance (sorry for bad english i'm french....)

Comment: I fixed the indentation in your code, but double-check it to make sure I got it right.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you add a print statement before `new_client.start()`, does it print? If you add a print statement at the top of the `run` method in `ClientThread`, does it print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this line of code in your `Server` instance `start` function:

```
new_client = threading.Thread(target=ClientThread,
     args=[len(self.CLIENTS), ip, port, clientsock])
```

The `target=` argument to `threading.Thread` needs to be a callable function.  Here `ClientThread` is the name of the constructor function for your class `ClientThread`, so it *is* a callable function, returning an instance of that class.  Note that it is not actually called yet!  The `args=` argument is more normally a tuple, but a list actually works.  These are the arguments that will be passed to the `target` function once it's eventually called, when you use this particular threading model.  (You can also pass keyword arguments using `kwargs=` and a dictionary.)

What happens now is a bit tricky.  Now that the two parameters (`target=` and `args=`) have been evaluated, the Python runtime creates a new instance of a `threading.Thread` class.  This new instance is, at the moment, *just* a data object.

If we add a `print` statement/function (it's not clear whether this is py2k or py3k code) we can see the object itself:

```
print('new_client id is', id(new_client))
```

which will print something like:<sup>1</sup>

```
new_client id is 34367605072
```

Next, you add this to a list and then invoke its `start`:

```
self.CLIENTS.append(new_client)
new_client.start()
```

The list add is straightforward enough, but the `start` is pretty tricky.

The `start` call itself actually creates a new OS/runtime thread (whose ID is not related to the data object's ID—the raw thread ID is an internal implementation detail).  This new thread starts running at its `run` method.<sup>2</sup>  The default `run` method is in fact:<sup>3</sup>

```
try:
    if self.__target:
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
finally:
    # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
    # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
    del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs
```

Since you are using a regular `threading.Thread` instance object, you are getting this default behavior, where `new_thread.start()` creates the new thread itself, which then calls the default `run` method, which calls its `self.__target` which is your `ClientThread` class-instance-creation function.

So *now*, inside the new thread, Python creates an instance of a `ClientThread` object, calling its `__init__` with the `self.__args` and `self.__kwargs` saved in the `new_thread` instance (which is itself shared between the original Python, and the new thread).

This new `ClientThread` object executes its `__init__` code and returns.  This is the equivalent of having the `run` method read:

```
def run(self):
    ClientThread(**saved_args)
```

Note that this is *not*:

```
def run(self):
    tmp = ClientThread(**saved_args)
    tmp.run()
```

That is, the `run` method of the `ClientThread` instance *is never called*.  Only the `run` method of the `threading.Thread` instance is called.  If you modify your `ClientThread`'s `__init__` method to print out *its* ID, you will see that this ID differs from that of the `threading.Thread` instance:

```
class ClientThread:
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_ip, client_port, socket):
        print('creating', id(self), 'instance')
```

which will print a different ID (and definitely print *after* the `new_client id is` line):

```
new_client id is 34367605072
creating 34367777464 instance
```

If you add additional `print`s to your `run` method you will see that it is never invoked.

#### What to do about this

You have two main options here.

- You can either make your `ClientThread` a *subclass* of `threading.Thread`:

  ```
  class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, client_id, client_ip, client_port, socket):
          ...
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  ```

  In this case, you would create the client object yourself, rather than using `threading.Thread` to create it:

  ```
  new_thread = ClientThread(...)
  ...
  new_thread.start()
  ```

  The `.start` method would be `threading.Thread.start` since you have not overridden that, and that method would then create the actual OS/runtime thread and then call your `run` method, which—since you *did* override it—would be *your* `run`.
- Or, you can create a standard `threading.Thread` object, supply it with a `target`, and have this `target` invoke your object's `run` method, e.g.:

  ```
  new_client = ClientThread(...)
  new_thread = threading.Thread(target=new_client.run, ...)
  ...
  new_thread.start()
  ```

  The choice is yours: to subclass, or to use separate objects.

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual ID is highly implementation-dependent.

<sup>2</sup>The path by which it reaches this `run` function is somewhat convoluted, passing through bootstrap code that does some internal initialization, then calls `self.run` for you, passing no arguments.  You are only promised that `self.run` gets entered somehow; you should not rely on the "how".

<sup>3</sup>At least, this is the code in Python 2.7 and 3.4; other implementations could vary slightly.